# Is this HDMI? If yes isn't it too small?

Tags: hdmi, docking-station

From left to right, I see something, then 3x USB-A, then RJ-45, and then HDMI, and two DisplayPorts. But, is the one which looks like HDMI really HDMI? Because it looks the same size as those USB-A's!! :

[image]

The width of USB-A is supposed to be [11.7 mm](https://images.app.goo.gl/VYkf39ujsZj1FG1QA), whereas the width of HDMI is supposed to be [14 mm](https://images.app.goo.gl/64TUuPZXV1PC4bJs5). So this image is confusing.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd20q.png

Answer (score 1):

The port to the right of the RJ45 socket is the HDMI port. Look closely (I did) and it the shape of an HDMI port (sides curve in at the bottom). Only a standard (not mini) HDMI port will go in that socket.  The HDMI port is 14 mm wide. The RJ45 socket beside it is 13.6 mm wide.

A port shaped like the port right of the RJ45 in the picture is a standard HDMI port in my experience to prevent making an error with any other type of connector.

Mini-HDMI is 10.4 mm and cannot be mistaken.

[Mini HDMI](https://tethertools.com/blog/what-are-hdmi-hdmi-mini-hdmi-micro-cables/)

> The Mini-HDMI connector is much smaller than a standard Type A plug.
> It measures 10.42 mm

Comment: Thanks John, but what about the size? That's confusing... Are there two sizes of HDMI ports?

Comment: It is same size (using the picture) as my own HDMI port.  9/16 " or 14 mm.  Only one size of HDMI.

Comment: @John - Except when you are dealing with mini-HDMI?

Comment: No. That is a standard HDMI port. Same size in my computers and TV sets.

Comment: @Ramhound is the one on the picture the mini HDMI then?

Comment: HDMI ports on most laptops are standard to take a standard cable to go into a standard monitor. Any way you can check the actual machine where you took the picture?  It is the same size roughly as the RJ45 port which is 13.6 mm.

Comment: @InnateImunityisTheWay - I was responding to the "only one size of HDMI" commentary.  To validate if it's HDMI or mini-HDMI look at the specifications for the device itself

Comment: I am pretty sure the one on the picture is mini-HDMI, just by the size comparison with other connectors.

Comment: I am going by the picture in your original post. The HDMI in the first picture is very close to the USB port beside it.